# Unable to render css and js files using Spark Java Template Engine

Tags: freemarker, spark-java

I'm new to Spark Java framework and I'm trying to render my html file using Freemarker template engine. But I'm not able to render my css and js files.

My project structure is as follows:

```
./pom.xml
./src/main/java/Spark.java
./src/main/resources/css/bootstrap.css
./src/main/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js
./src/main/resources/js/app.js
./src/main/resources/templates/search.ftl
```

The main method is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        staticFileLocation("/css");
        staticFileLocation("/Content/Images");
        staticFileLocation("/fonts");
        staticFileLocation("/js");

        final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(Spark.class, "/");

        get("/searchview", (request, response) -> {

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

            try {
                Template searchTemplate = configuration.getTemplate("templates/search.ftl");

                searchTemplate.process(null, writer);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                halt(500);
            }

            return writer;
        });
}
```

And now when I enter url: localhost:4567/searchview, my HTML page gets rendered but the css and js is not.

In my console it says: INFO spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/css/bootstrap.min.css] has not been mapped in Spark

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your subsequent `staticFileLocation` calls will override your previously set static file locations. Create a folder called `public` under your `src/main/resources` and then place your `css`, `fonts`, `js` and any other static folders under there. Finally set your static file location by `staticFileLocation("/public")`.